# Javascript Runtime error - JQM Page Transitions - ajaxEnabled=?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm building a hybrid app with Cordova, using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 in Visual Studio.
I need the page transition effects, so i **don't** want to turn off ajax.

However i get a `0x800c001c JavaScript Runtime Error` at `Line 3, column 14955` of `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`, whenever i click on a link to change the page. If i set `ajaxEnabled=false` then it navigates to the second page but without transition effects.

I am using the Single Page per File template either for the first page and for the second.

1. Can someone explain what exactly needs `ajaxEnabled` to be false?
2. Is there any other default that i can set so the app will work
   properly?

Comment: 1) Use the unminified version of jQuery 2) test the app in a browser: does the error persists?

Comment: i cannot test the app in a browser because of external linking.
which files of uniminified jQM should i include?

Comment: i tried all possible combinations, no result..

Comment: I meant, using the unminified version, please update your error log with the new line/column (and maybe the stack trace)

Comment: use apache httpd server and place your www folder in htdocs then run your application... every thing will work fine